# Would appreciate assistance with .OrderBy and group/cross join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two part issue here. First, I am to narrow a list of class instances by the value of of the keys. This, I have accomplished; however, next I am to store the results in ascending order by the last name of the person. I could probably handle this, except the name string contains first and last name in the value. How can I order the instances of the class by the last name of the name string? I'm certain this is an instance where .OrderBy is the solution, but I don't know where to insert it into my .ToList() argument and how to tell the compiler which character to use for the sorting.

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() {
  new Customer(){ Name="Bob Lesman", Balance=80345.66, Bank="FTB"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Joe Landy", Balance=9284756.21, Bank="WF"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Meg Ford", Balance=487233.01, Bank="BOA"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Peg Vale", Balance=7001449.92, Bank="BOA"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Mike Johnson", Balance=790872.12, Bank="WF"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Les Paul", Balance=8374892.54, Bank="WF"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Sid Crosby", Balance=957436.39, Bank="FTB"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Sarah Ng", Balance=56562389.85, Bank="FTB"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Tina Fey", Balance=1000000.00, Bank="CITI"},
  new Customer(){ Name="Sid Brown", Balance=49582.68, Bank="CITI"}
        };

List<ReportItem> millionaireReport = customers.Where(customer => customer.Balance >= 1000000).Select(customer => new ReportItem( customer.Name, customer.Bank )).ToList();

List<Bank> banks = new List<Bank>() {
  new Bank(){ Name="First Tennessee", Symbol="FTB"},
  new Bank(){ Name="Wells Fargo", Symbol="WF"},
  new Bank(){ Name="Bank of America", Symbol="BOA"},
  new Bank(){ Name="Citibank", Symbol="CITI"},
        };
```

The continuation of the exercise is to Console.WriteLine the filtered and ordered results with the bank name in place of the abbreviation / ticker symbol in the manner of "{Customer.Name} at {Bank.Name}". We're told to read and attempt using Group Join or maybe Cross Join. I have read through the example, but am still trying to understand. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The hard part would be figuring out which part of the name is the "last name" part as not all cultures are the same (e.g. will some customers have a middle name - or two, also some cultures put their "family name" first).

The most simple solution would be something like:

```
customers.OrderBy(c=>c.Name.Split(' ')[1].ToUpper())
```

although this presumes that names will always be formatted like:

```
$"{firstName} {lastName}"
```

with no other spaces and no middle name. It also doesnt take into account Family name prefixes like 'McDouglas'

As for the matching Bank Symbol to Bank Name:

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    var bank = banks.FirstOrDefault(b=>string.Equals(b.Symbol, customer.Bank, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCore)
    if (bank != default)
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: ```OrderBy(c=>c.Name.Split(' ')[1]``` was exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly. Thank you. Any thoughts on the second part of the exercise; joining the bank's full name to it's ticker symbol?

Comment: @CharlesBelcher I have updated my answer to include the second part of the question. if this answers your question please mark my answer as correct (tick underneath the answer score)